# Navigating to Angular Component leads to 127.0.0.1 error not found

Tags: angular, typescript, httpserver

My Angular Application was working perfectly when I built using ng build --prod and served with http-server -o.  However, something happened and now I get 404 error everytime my app should be loading a new component

I've tried restarting my computer, rebuilding, reverting to git commits that have worked in the past, and updating my service worker.  Nothing has worked.

```
const appRoutes: Routes=[
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'whoconebioassayphase1', component: WhoConeBioassayPhase1Component},
  {path: 'editwhoconebioassayphase1', component: Editwhoconebioassayphase1Component},
  {path: 'exphutintro', component: ExpHutIntroComponent},
  {path: 'exphut', component: ExpHutComponent},
  {path: 'editexphutintro', component: EditexphutintroComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WhoConeBioassayPhase1Component,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    Editwhoconebioassayphase1Component,
    ExpHutIntroComponent,
    ExpHutComponent,
    EditexphutintroComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpClientModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule

  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hard to tell from what you have here. What is in your environment files.

Comment: Just my Firebase Keys

Comment: My guess would be something with the service worker. I believe there was a bug with http-server and service workers. I used a different package npm serve. Then you can use npm build -prod, cd into dist, then serve

Comment: what command did you use to serve?  Also, were you in dist/ or dist/<project> ?

Comment: Maybe your base route is wrong in index.html? Also do you navigate with the angular router from your root or typing the URL directly in the browser?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve was the package I use to  to locally serve a productive build with service workers. You install it globally so you use the serve command in the /dist folder

Comment: @Fussel I navigate with the angular router

Comment: @Fussel I used "/" as my base href

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `useHash` option to your router.

So instead of:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
```

do this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true})],
```

If that solves your problem, here are [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy).